Customizing VS Code Integrated Terminal Color Theme *For Each Terminal Program*
I'm aware that one can customize the color theme of the VS Code integrated terminal (separately from the color theme of the editor itself) by using methods explained here. As can be seen in the screenshot below, however, I have multiple types of terminals that I may want to use--perhaps even simultaneously, and it would be great if these were visually different. For instance, I'd like it if the color theme for Git Bash and the color theme for Command Prompt were different. Is it possible to achieve this, and if so, how?

I looked through this documentation page and looked for related questions on SO, but I didn't find anything that looked like an answer to this question.
